# Android studio3.1.4 sync failed:

Tags: android, android-studio

This is my error statement: please help me i am struggling from the last four days.
I have completely uninstall android studio so many times, still unable to run a single application.

C:\Users\Sajjad Athar.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-4.4-all\9br9xq1tocpiv8o6njlyu5op1\gradle-4.4\src\core-api\org\gradle\api\artifacts\repositories\FlatDirectoryArtifactRepository.java (The file or directory is corrupted and unreadable)

Comment: please add more info

Comment: this is exact error statement

Comment: change gradle-wrapper.properties file inside distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-all.zip

Comment: just `invalidate caches and restart`.

Comment: NOT having success

Comment: gradle sync failed the file directory is corrupt and unreadable

Comment: "Gradle sync failed: The file or directory is corrupted and unreadable
    Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log) (474ms)"

Comment: please anybody come up with solution